# How do i get the node id using menu_hook

Tags: routes

Hi I try to get the node id when user edit the node by the code below:

```
       function test_plugin_menu(){
            $item = array();
            $item['node/%/edit'] = array(
                'page callback' => 'test_plugin',
                'page arguments' => array(1),
                'access callback' => TRUE,
                'type' =>  MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
            );
            return $item; 
        }

        function test_plugin($node_id){
              dpm($node_id); 
         }
```

I get into a blank page when i edit a node. Please help, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you pass a node id into the url, it get's converted to a fully loaded node by the time your callback function is called. You could read up on it on the documentation page for [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), under section `Auto-Loader Wildcards`.

In `node.module` you will see this menu item for node edit:

```
$items['node/%node/edit']
```

Now, the path you are trying to register already exists in the node module, so that is where the WSOD comes from. You need to do a [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) on it, or perhaps [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) if all you want to do is alter the node edit form.

Comment: hi thanks for your response. I think you are correct about the call back. My aim is just to get node id of the editing to perform some check up. Is there anyway to append the call back using hook_menu_alter() ?

Comment: Hi I used hook_node_load() to solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: You are right I ended up using hook_form_alter